# watching variables values while nodejs running without stopping at breakpoints

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, watch

I'm working on a NodeJS project using nodejs 8.1.2 and the IDE is intellij Ultimate.

in general I don't mind using any other editor or kind of debugger if it allows it.

I want to see variables values in real time without stopping at break points at all.

is that at all possible ?

I noticed that google chrome inspect debugger and intellij doesn't do that.. I can't remember ever seeing this feature. so any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [spy-js](https://github.com/spy-js/spy-js) - it allows inspecting variables, etc. without adding breakpoints. See  https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/04/spy-js-webstorm-secret-service/#workflow for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this feature either.

What I'd do to watch a variable is this:

```
function watch(variable) {
  setInterval(() => { console.log(variable) }, 1000)
}

watch(varaiableToWatch)
```

Above is a very simple solution with the tradeoff of creating noise in the console logs.

If you want a fully-featured library, this will do the trick: https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/